# Java string == Vs Equals giving true or false when combined with concatenation

Tags: java

I'm definitely missing something

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "abc";
    System.out.println(s1 ==  s2);//gives true
}

public static void main(String []args){
    String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "abc";
    System.out.println("s1 == s2 is:" + s1 ==  s2); //gives false
 }
```

something to do with operator precedence??

Comment: On a side note, don't compare Strings with `==`, use `equals(String)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(String)`

Comment: Although in this case, it _would_ work as expected if you added the parentheses, since you're comparing string constants (which are guaranteed by JLS to be `==` if they're `equals`).

Comment: Note to those who will answer "don't use `==` to compare Strings": it looks as though that's the intended behavior, an investigation of (interned) String constants in Java.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the [`+` operator is of higher precedence than `==`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), so you are comparing the string `"s1 == s2 is:abc"` to `"abc"`.  You can always use parentheses to force an explicit order of operations.

Answer (score 2):

Yup. It's evaluated as:

```
("s1 == s2 is:" + s1) ==  s2
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by others Yes '+' operator has more precedence then the '=='. If you enclose the comparison within parenthesis like

```
   System.out.println("s1 == s2 is"+(s1 == s2));
```

The above statement will give true since parenthesis is having higher precedence than +.

If you feel why string s1 and s2 are referring to the same memory location then it is because of string literal pool concept.

Answer (score 0):

`+` opertator has higher precidence then == so you are doing "s1 == s2 is:abc" to "abc".

Note that use equal or equalIgnoreCase to comparing the String always because == always compares reference

Answer (score 0):

dude you are not supposed to use == for string comparison instead use equals method.

```
string1.equals(string2)
```

Comment: That's true in general, but it's not the answer in this case. Firstly, the operator precedence makes it a moot point; and secondly, if you fixed the operator precedence (by adding parentheses), it would print `s1 == s2 is:true` because OP is comparing string constants.

Comment: == for string is overloaded to check underlying values.
dude s1 is string  NOT s1 = new String("abc")

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @user1635354 No, Strings do not overload `==`. Nothing does or can overload `==` in Java. It compares the objects for reference equality, same as it does for any reference types.