# Why System.out.println() doesn't print the string

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = new String("Haseeb"); 
        String str2 = new String("Haseeb");
        System.out.println("str1==str2" + str1==str2  );
    }
}
```

- output is "false"
- I am expecting "str1==str2 false"

Comment: I do not believe. Your expectations are correct. You should get `str==str2false`

Comment: Related (though not exactly a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585536

Answer (score 12):

The `==` operator [is of lower precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `+`, so `+` gets execute first.

`"str1==str2" + str1` yields `"str1==str2Haseeb"`.

Then `==` executes, and `"str1==str2Haseeb"` is not the same object as `"Haseeb"` (`str2`), so `false` is printed.

You can add parentheses to clarify the desired order of operations.

```
System.out.println("str1==str2 " + (str1==str2)  );
```

This should print `str1==str2 false`.

Answer (score 4):

`(a + b == c)` evaluates as `(a + b) == c`, not `a + (b==c)`, because `+` has higher precedence than `==`. Otherwise arithmetic wouldn't work.

What you have there is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println( ("str1==str2" + str1) ==str2  );
```

And `("str1==str2" + str1)` is not equal to `str2`, so you print `false`.

What you probably mean is:

```
System.out.println("str1==str2 " + (str1==str2));
```